# What is the meaning of 多所 in 这项联合多所医学院校所做的研究发现？

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> 这项联合多所医学院校所做的研究发现，除了个别人以外，多数人体重的增加会从周六开始，...

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 16.

What is the meaning of 多所？

Comment: As with your earlier question, the general expectation here is to show some kind of effort.  Usually that means looking up words in a dictionary or using Google Translate, and explaining why those methods aren't suitable.  Showing where you're stuck helps people answer such questions.  (Without this, someone could copy/paste the sentence into Google Translate and copy/paste the result as an answer; this doesn't help anyone.)

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for not following the strict rules. I will be more careful in my next questions.

Answer (score 1):

Not 多所 as one word.
所 is the 量词 for 医学院校
项 is the 量词 for 研究

这项联合多所医学院校所做的研究发现，
This 项 study, carried out in conjunction with various 所 medical schools found that,
除了个别人以外，
apart from a few individuals,
多数人体重的增加会从周六开始，
the majority people increase their body weight starting on Saturday,

Get fat on Sat!

You could shorten that long and winding first part:

这项研究发现，

Answer (score 1):

多 means "multi", "many", or "numerous".

所 is the "measure word" for building/school/college.

多所医学院校 - multiple medical colleges, or several medical colleges.